# SQL Query / Regular Expression to Split Custom string into columns

Tags: sql, regex, database, oracle, db2

Hi I have source data in a field in different formats like below

1Y3M6D (1 Year, 3 Months, 6 Days) I need to split this into 3 fields Year, Month, Days but the source data format can change like month can come first as 3M1Y6D OR source data can only have 3M with no year and day. How do I write a query to get the preceding number from M, Y or D?

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: oracle or db2? please only tag one dbms you are actually using.

Comment: Please provide the query you have tried so far or what;s your plan of action? 
So that you can get further help.

Comment: I have tried something like this select my_value, substr(my_value,1,1) Y, substr(my_value, 3,1) M, substr(my_value,5,1) D from 
(
select '1Y3M6D' my_value from dual
); but I am looking for something dynamic

Comment: The base way to do this would be to search for the "token" (eg, `'M'`), then work backwards until you hit another token (or the start of the string).  The longer term way to do it would be to create a custom type.

Comment: Consider trying `REGEXP_SUBSTR(my_value,'(\d+)Y',1,1,NULL,1)` for year, etc in 11g onwards

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone, Unoembre command helped.
select my_value, REGEXP_SUBSTR(my_value,'(\d+)Y',1,1,NULL,1) REG_Y, REGEXP_SUBSTR(my_value,'(\d+)M',1,1,NULL,1) REG_M, REGEXP_SUBSTR(my_value,'(\d+)D',1,1,NULL,1) REG_D from ( select '3M6Y2D' my_value from dual );